# Point inside Oriented Bounding Box?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, geometry

I have an OBB2D class based on SAT.

This is my point in OBB method:

```
public boolean pointInside(float x, float y)
{
    float newy = (float) (Math.sin(angle) * (y - center.y) + Math.cos(angle) *
            (x - center.x));
    float newx = (float) (Math.cos(angle) * (x - center.x) - Math.sin(angle) * 
            (y - center.y));
    return (newy > center.y - (getHeight() / 2)) && 
            (newy < center.y + (getHeight() / 2)) 
            && (newx > center.x - (getWidth() / 2)) && 
            (newx < center.x + (getWidth() / 2));
}

public boolean pointInside(Vector2D v)
{
    return pointInside(v.x,v.y);
}
```

Here is the rest of the class; the parts that pertain:

```
public class OBB2D
{
   private Vector2D projVec = new Vector2D();
   private static Vector2D projAVec = new Vector2D();
   private static Vector2D projBVec = new Vector2D();
   private static Vector2D tempNormal = new Vector2D();
   private Vector2D deltaVec = new Vector2D();
   private ArrayList<Vector2D> collisionPoints = new ArrayList<Vector2D>();


// Corners of the box, where 0 is the lower left.
   private  Vector2D corner[] = new Vector2D[4];

   private Vector2D center = new Vector2D();
   private Vector2D extents = new Vector2D();

   private RectF boundingRect = new RectF();
   private float angle;

    //Two edges of the box extended away from corner[0]. 
   private  Vector2D axis[] = new Vector2D[2];

   private double origin[] = new double[2];

   public OBB2D(float centerx, float centery, float w, float h, float angle)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < corner.length; ++i)
       {
           corner[i] = new Vector2D();
       }
       for(int i = 0; i < axis.length; ++i)
       {
           axis[i] = new Vector2D();
       }
       set(centerx,centery,w,h,angle);
    }

   public OBB2D(float left, float top, float width, float height)
  {
       for(int i = 0; i < corner.length; ++i)
       {
           corner[i] = new Vector2D();
       }
       for(int i = 0; i < axis.length; ++i)
       {
           axis[i] = new Vector2D();
       }
       set(left + (width / 2), top + (height / 2),width,height,0.0f);
   }

   public void set(float centerx,float centery,float w, float h,float angle)
   {
       float vxx = (float)Math.cos(angle);
       float vxy = (float)Math.sin(angle);
       float vyx = (float)-Math.sin(angle);
       float vyy = (float)Math.cos(angle);

           vxx *= w / 2;
           vxy *= (w / 2);
           vyx *= (h / 2);
           vyy *= (h / 2);

           corner[0].x = centerx - vxx - vyx;
           corner[0].y = centery - vxy - vyy;
           corner[1].x = centerx + vxx - vyx;
           corner[1].y = centery + vxy - vyy;
           corner[2].x = centerx + vxx + vyx;
           corner[2].y = centery + vxy + vyy;
           corner[3].x = centerx - vxx + vyx;
           corner[3].y = centery - vxy + vyy;

           this.center.x = centerx;
           this.center.y = centery;
           this.angle = angle;
           computeAxes();
           extents.x = w / 2;
           extents.y = h / 2;

           computeBoundingRect();
   }


   //Updates the axes after the corners move.  Assumes the
   //corners actually form a rectangle.
   private void computeAxes()
   {
       axis[0].x = corner[1].x - corner[0].x;
       axis[0].y = corner[1].y - corner[0].y;
       axis[1].x = corner[3].x - corner[0].x;
       axis[1].y = corner[3].y - corner[0].y;


       // Make the length of each axis 1/edge length so we know any
       // dot product must be less than 1 to fall within the edge.

       for (int a = 0; a < axis.length; ++a) 
       {
        float l = axis[a].length();
        float ll = l * l;
        axis[a].x = axis[a].x / ll;
        axis[a].y = axis[a].y / ll;
           origin[a] = corner[0].dot(axis[a]);
       }
   }



   public void computeBoundingRect()
   {
       boundingRect.left = JMath.min(JMath.min(corner[0].x, corner[3].x), JMath.min(corner[1].x, corner[2].x));
       boundingRect.top = JMath.min(JMath.min(corner[0].y, corner[1].y),JMath.min(corner[2].y, corner[3].y));
       boundingRect.right = JMath.max(JMath.max(corner[1].x, corner[2].x), JMath.max(corner[0].x, corner[3].x));
       boundingRect.bottom = JMath.max(JMath.max(corner[2].y, corner[3].y),JMath.max(corner[0].y, corner[1].y)); 
   }

   public void set(RectF rect)
   {
       set(rect.centerX(),rect.centerY(),rect.width(),rect.height(),0.0f);
   }

    // Returns true if other overlaps one dimension of this.
    private boolean overlaps1Way(OBB2D other)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < axis.length; ++a) {

            double t = other.corner[0].dot(axis[a]);

            // Find the extent of box 2 on axis a
            double tMin = t;
            double tMax = t;

            for (int c = 1; c < corner.length; ++c) {
                t = other.corner[c].dot(axis[a]);

                if (t < tMin) {
                    tMin = t;
                } else if (t > tMax) {
                    tMax = t;
                }
            }

            // We have to subtract off the origin

            // See if [tMin, tMax] intersects [0, 1]
            if ((tMin > 1 + origin[a]) || (tMax < origin[a])) {
                // There was no intersection along this dimension;
                // the boxes cannot possibly overlap.
                return false;
            }
        }

        // There was no dimension along which there is no intersection.
        // Therefore the boxes overlap.
        return true;
    }



    public void moveTo(float centerx, float centery) 
    {
        float cx,cy;

        cx = center.x;
        cy = center.y;

        deltaVec.x = centerx - cx;
        deltaVec.y  = centery - cy;


        for (int c = 0; c < 4; ++c)
        {
            corner[c].x += deltaVec.x;
            corner[c].y += deltaVec.y;
        }

        boundingRect.left += deltaVec.x;
        boundingRect.top += deltaVec.y;
        boundingRect.right += deltaVec.x;
        boundingRect.bottom += deltaVec.y;


        this.center.x = centerx;
        this.center.y = centery;
        computeAxes();
    }

    // Returns true if the intersection of the boxes is non-empty.
    public boolean overlaps(OBB2D other)
    {
        if(right() < other.left())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(bottom() < other.top())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(left() > other.right())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(top() > other.bottom())
        {
            return false;
        }


        if(other.getAngle() == 0.0f && getAngle() == 0.0f)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return overlaps1Way(other) && other.overlaps1Way(this);
    }

    public Vector2D getCenter()
    {
        return center;
    }

    public float getWidth()
    {
        return extents.x * 2;
    }

    public float getHeight() 
    {
        return extents.y * 2;
    }

    public void setAngle(float angle)
    {
        set(center.x,center.y,getWidth(),getHeight(),angle);
    }

    public float getAngle()
    {
        return angle;
    }

    public void setSize(float w,float h)
    {
        set(center.x,center.y,w,h,angle);
    }

    public float left()
    {
        return boundingRect.left;
    }

    public float right()
    {
        return boundingRect.right;
    }

    public float bottom()
    {
        return boundingRect.bottom;
    }

    public float top()
    {
        return boundingRect.top;
    }

    public RectF getBoundingRect()
    {
        return boundingRect;
    }

    public boolean overlaps(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)
    {
        if(right() < left)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(bottom() < top)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(left() > right)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(top() > bottom)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static float distance(float ax, float ay,float bx, float by)
    {
      if (ax < bx)
        return bx - ay;
      else
        return ax - by;
    }


    public Vector2D project(float ax, float ay)
    {
        projVec.x = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        projVec.y = Float.MIN_VALUE;

      for (int i = 0; i < corner.length; ++i)
      {
        float dot = Vector2D.dot(corner[i].x,corner[i].y,ax,ay);

        projVec.x = JMath.min(dot, projVec.x);
        projVec.y = JMath.max(dot, projVec.y);
      }

      return projVec;
    }

    public Vector2D getCorner(int c)
    {
        return corner[c];
    }

    public int getNumCorners()
    {
        return corner.length;
    }


    public boolean pointInside(float x, float y)
    {
        float newy = (float) (Math.sin(angle) * (y - center.y) + Math.cos(angle) *
                (x - center.x));
        float newx = (float) (Math.cos(angle) * (x - center.x) - Math.sin(angle) * 
                (y - center.y));
        return (newy > center.y - (getHeight() / 2)) && 
                (newy < center.y + (getHeight() / 2)) 
                && (newx > center.x - (getWidth() / 2)) && 
                (newx < center.x + (getWidth() / 2));
    }

    public boolean pointInside(Vector2D v)
    {
        return pointInside(v.x,v.y);
    }

    public ArrayList<Vector2D> getCollsionPoints(OBB2D b)
    {

        collisionPoints.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < corner.length; ++i)
        {
            if(b.pointInside(corner[i]))
            {
                collisionPoints.add(corner[i]);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < b.corner.length; ++i)
        {
            if(pointInside(b.corner[i]))
            {
                collisionPoints.add(b.corner[i]);
            }
        }
        return collisionPoints;
    }
};
```

What could be wrong? When I getCollisionPoints for 2 OBBs I know are penetrating, it returns no points.

Thanks

I also tried:

```
public boolean pointInside(float x, float y)
{
    float xx = (x - center.x);
    float yy =  (y - center.y);
    float newx = (float) (xx * Math.cos(angle) - yy * Math.sin(angle));
    float newy = (float) (xx * Math.sin(angle) + yy * Math.cos(angle));
    return (newy > center.y - (getHeight() / 2)) && 
            (newy < center.y + (getHeight() / 2)) 
            && (newx > center.x - (getWidth() / 2)) && 
            (newx < center.x + (getWidth() / 2));
}
```

With no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read all of your class, but I'm assuming `angle` is the angle by which you would need to rotate your rectangle clockwise in order to make it axis-aligned.

I believe that both `sin(angle) * (y-center.y)` and `cos(angle) * (x-center.x)` are equal to the distance between your center point and the point you're testing. So `newy` will always equal twice that distance, and `newx` will always equal 0.

This is how I prefer to rotate a point about another point: get the angle and distance between the two points, then apply the rotation to the angle, then calculate the new position from the angle and distance. In pseudocode:

```
//takes a point and rotates it `theta` angles 
//counterclockwise around the given center point
function rotateAboutPoint(x,y, centerX, centerY, theta){
    radius = sqrt((centerX-x)**2 + (centerY-y)**2)  //`**` is the exponentiation operator
    currentAngle = atan2(y-centerY, x-centerX)      //prefer `atan2` over ordinary `atan` if you can get it
    newAngle = currentAngle + theta
    newX = centerX + radius*cos(newAngle)
    newY = centerY + radius*sin(newAngle)
    return (newX, newY)
}

function pointInside(x,y){
    //point must be rotated clockwise, so we provide a negative angle
    newX, newY = rotateAboutPoint(x,y,center.x, center.y, -angle) 
    return (
        newY  > center.y - (getHeight() / 2) &&
        newY  < center.y + (getHeight() / 2) &&
        newX  > center.x - (getHeight() / 2) &&
        newX  < center.x + (getHeight() / 2) &&
    )
}
```