# I am using javaFx and i am trying to determine if a point is inside a bounding box

Tags: java, canvas, boolean

This is the class that i am using

```
public class Spot {

private static final int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 500;
private static final int IMAGE_WIDTH = 500;

private static final int DOT_HEIGHT = 20;
private static final int DOT_WIDTH = 20;

private static final Color DOT_COLOR = Color.RED;
private Random ran = new Random();

private int x = this.ran.nextInt(IMAGE_WIDTH);
private int y = this.ran.nextInt(IMAGE_HEIGHT);
/**
 * Draws spot onto given playfield object
 * 
 * @param playfield 
 */
public void drawSpot(Playfield playfield) {
    playfield.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(DOT_COLOR);
    playfield.getGraphicsContext2D().fillOval(x, y, DOT_WIDTH, DOT_HEIGHT);
    this.drawSpot(playfield);

}
```

I am trying to figure out a way to write a method that would determine if the given x and y coordinate is inside the bounding box.

```
public boolean isINSpot(int x, int y){
        if (x > this.x && x < this.x + DOT_WIDTH && y > this.y && y < this.y + DOT_HEIGHT) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Point inside Oriented Bounding Box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493070/point-inside-oriented-bounding-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

```
return x > boxX && x < boxX + boxWidth && y > boxY && y < boxY + boxHeight;
```

If not, I messed up.

Comment: Would this have to be inside an if statement to return false if i wrote a test class with assertTrue to make sure a point was inside the dot?

Comment: It is in the isINspot method